# push values of multidimensional array to an array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have this multidimensional hash %HASH:

```
 'BBBL' => {
',                   'VALUE' => 'CASH
                     'DATES' => '20163112'
                      },
  'AAA' => {
',                   'VALUE' => '70
                     'DATES' => '20170602'
  'CCC' => {
',                   'VALUE' => '70
                     'DATES' => '20170602'
```

and for each of AAA BBB and CCC i want to push the DATES into an array.

```
foreach my $symbol (keys %HASH){
     my @dates = values %HASH;
    }
```

but that gives me:

```
            'VALUE' => 'CASH
            'DATES' => '20163112'
          },
          {
',          'VALUE' => '90
            'DATES' => '20170802'
          },
          {
',          'VALUE' => '90
            'DATES' => '20171702'
          }
        ];
```

and I have no idea how to get just the dates.

Comment: Note that your values seem to be terminated with a Carriage Return?!

Comment: What is a field that contains a single date called "dates"?

Comment: yes it is called dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
my @dates;
for my $symbol (keys %HASH){
    push @dates, $HASH{$symbol}{DATES};
}
```

This could be simplified to:

```
my @dates;
for my $subhash (values %HASH){
    push @dates, $subhash->{DATES};
}
```

Which in turn could be rewritten as:

```
my @dates = map $_->{DATES}, values %HASH;
```

---

Side note: It seems like your `VALUE` fields contain a carriage return (CR, `\r`) at the end. If you used Data::Dumper to produce your output, you might want to set `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` to make the dump more readable.